# function identifier and variable identifier relations?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

is the function names in a c program a variable that hold the starting address of the function body in low level?

Example:

```
int x = 0;
```

here x is an identifier for and address in memory is it true for function names also?

```
int sample(int x, int y) {

    ////code here
    return 0;

}
```

I guess:

here sample is and identifier for an address in memory that hold the starting point of the function in memory.

Comment: Can't speak for C since I never had cause to look it up, but in C++ (you tagged it, sucker, so no you have to read the ol' man rant), a function is one of the few things [that isn't an object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object).

Comment: I think the only answer to your question is that it is not specified by the C++ standard or C standard, and is an implementation detail (so any reliance on the implementation behavior will not necessarily be portable).

Answer (score 5):

A function name is some sort of handle to the function—it is some thing that provides a way to call the function. In many C implementations, it is the address of the machine code of the function (in the virtual memory used in the running program). However, in some C implementations, it may be the address of a data structure that provides further information about the function, such as what registers the function uses and where its code is located in memory.

Comment: A function is a block of code which only runs when it is called. It might make more sense to explain what a function reference or function pointer represents when compiled. On modern architectures calling a function pointer will simply compile to a `CALL` with an address stored in a register or in memory.

Answer (score 1):

A function name simply identifies a series of statements to be executed. If the compiler knows what those statements are (because the function is defined in the translation unit in which the name appears) then the compiler is free to replace the expression which invokes that function with anything whose execution will provably have the same effect as executing the function.

A simple case of this substitution is *inlining*, but the compiler and slice and dice as it sees fit. It can introduce a branch statement rather than a function call if the call is in tail position. It can inline part of the function, leaving another part as a piece of unnamed code which is called from different places. (That would typically be done if the not-inlined part is not always needed.) And there are many other possibilities. In that sense, the function name does not need to identify a unique object at all.

Some function names are converted to function pointers, and some function names have external linkage. In both cases, the compiler may no longer know what the execution effect of the function is. (In the case of standard library functions, the compiler could know, so the invocation of a standard library function might be replaced with code which has the same execution effect, just as with a function defined in the translation unit.)

Function pointers are first-class objects, but they are not same as functions despite the fact that the syntax attempts to hide that from you by automatically dereferencing function pointers and automatically converting function names to function pointers when necessary. Once a function pointer has been created, it must be a value from which the entry point of the function can be derived. C and C++ both guarantee that two function pointers to the same function will compare equal, which limits the options for how the function pointer is internally represented. Even so, there is no guarantee that it contains the address in memory of the implementation of the function. It might, for example, involve an extra level of indirection by pointing to a structure which describes the code to be called, or it might be some kind of trampoline which lazily resolves finds the function's implementation the first time it is invoked. (These techniques are frequently used for external references to function names with external linkage.)

If a function has external linkage, then its name can be used in a different translation unit as a way to invoke the function. That means that the name needs to correspond in some way with a body of code which can be called. Eventually, the mapping has to allow the computation of the address of some machine instruction, which will be the entry point of the function. But that computation does not have to be done at compile time (and rarely is). And even if your code creates a function pointer, it is entirely possible that the pointer is not simply the entry point address. It could, for example, be the address of a relocation entry in a jump table, or it could be the address of a trampoline function.

In short, the relationship between a function name and an address in memory is a lot less definitive than the relationship between a variable name and an address in memory, although in reality variables without external linkage whose addresses are never taken might also not correspond to a memory address. (For example, the name might just refer to the current home of a value which happens to be temporarily occupying a hardware register.)

In short, while it's tempting to use a computation model in which names are some kind of alias for a particular memory address, it's not a very exact model and it might lead you to make incorrect assumptions about the nature of executable.